# How to remove duplicates, which are generated with array_agg postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, array-agg

Does anyone an idea how to rewrite following SQL query to generate results, that would contains only one occurrence of name? (results grouped by user).

**The query**

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname)), ', ')
FROM log_has_item logitem
  INNER JOIN log log ON log.id = logitem.log_id
  INNER JOIN worker u ON log.worker_id = u.id
WHERE logitem.company_id = 1
```

Executable query is avaiable on **[sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b911f/5)**. 
Click on Run SQL button and you will result, which contains *Frantisek Smith* twice

Comment: `array_agg(distinct concat(...)))`

Comment: In postgre 9.0+ there is `string_agg(text,text)` function. It may be easier to write `string_agg(CONCAT(...),', ')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name distinct works fine, but scrambles the order. Any way to preserve it?

Comment: @Rodrigo: use an `order by` inside `string_agg()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried string_agg(distinct nome order by l.id,', ') and string_agg(distinct nome order by nome,', '), but both give "function string_agg(character varying) does not exist". I'll ask a question with the full sql to show you.

Comment: @Rodrigo `string_agg(distinct nome, ',' order by l.id)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Now it gives "in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35774675/1086511

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can use the `distinct` keyword inside `array_agg`:

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname)), ', ')
FROM log_has_item logitem
  INNER JOIN log log ON log.id = logitem.log_id
  INNER JOIN worker u ON log.worker_id = u.id
WHERE logitem.company_id = 1
```

[SQLFiddle with this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b911f/8/0)

Comment: Any way to preserve the order using distinct?

Comment: ERROR: DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions
SQL State :0A000  (PostgreSQL 9.5.5)

Comment: Saved me from having to write my own aggregate function!

Comment: Wouldn't `STRING_AGG` be better? See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

No need to go all round the houses with `ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(` when a simple [`STRING_AGG`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-aggregate.html) will do as follows (code available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5eee9043f6043440ea69729fc3fea032)):

```
--
-- Simplified
--

SELECT
  DISTINCT
  STRING_AGG
  (
    DISTINCT CONCAT(w.firstname, ' ', w.lastname), ', '
  ) AS "The workers"
FROM log_item li
INNER JOIN log l ON li.log_id = l.id 
INNER JOIN worker w ON l.worker_id = w.id
WHERE li.company_id = 1;
```

Result:

```
                The workers
Frantisek Smith, Peter Duff
```