# Join multiple table on array column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, database-design

I have many tables to join, some of them have joining columns as array,

When I tried with two tables it worked fine

```
select 
        tr.report_id,
        tr.sponsor_ids,
        array_agg(tsp.sponsor)
    --from public.tbl_report_page trp
    from  public.tbl_report tr --on trp.report_id = tr.report_id

    left join public.tbl_sponsor tsp on tsp.sponsor_id = any(tr.sponsor_ids)

    --left join public.tbl_tag tg on tg.tag_id = any(tr.tags)

    group by tr.report_id,tr.sponsor_ids--,trp.page_id
    having tr.report_id = 109
```

This works fine,

> 109   {1,2,3,4,5,6}   "{sponsor_1,sponsor_2,sponsor_3,sponsor_4,sponsor_5,sponsor_6}"

but when I uncomment

```
left join public.tbl_tag tg on tg.tag_id = any(tr.tags)
```

getting lots of values in sponsors

```
109 {1,2,3,4,5,6}   "{sponsor_1,sponsor_1,sponsor_1,sponsor_2,sponsor_2,sponsor_2,sponsor_3,sponsor_3,sponsor_3,sponsor_4,sponsor_4,sponsor_4,sponsor_5,sponsor_5,sponsor_5,sponsor_6,sponsor_6,sponsor_6}"
```

I have to add more tables which contains ids as array.

Comment: You could solve this, and many other future issues, by changing your schema and not using arrays for this. Stick to 3NF and you wouldn't have this issue. One record, one column, one value.

Comment: I have to stick with array columns, it's as per requirement

Comment: Are you looking for distinct for array_agg like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363742/how-to-remove-duplicates-which-are-generated-with-array-agg-postgres-function)?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, it's typically superior to replace those arrays with normalized many-to-many relationships in your relational design. See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)

While stuck with your current design, consider how joins can multiply rows:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)

Your query probably works like this:

```sql
SELECT tr.report_id
     , tr.sponsor_ids
     , sp.sponsors
     , sp.tags
FROM   public.tbl_report tr
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT tsp.sponsor) AS sponsors
        , array_agg(DISTINCT tg.tag) AS tags
   FROM   public.tbl_sponsor tsp
   LEFT   JOIN public.tbl_tag tg ON tg.tag_id = ANY (tr.tags)
   WHERE  tsp.sponsor_id = ANY (tr.sponsor_ids)   
   ) sp ON true
WHERE  tr.report_id = 109;
```

Depending on your actual objective, more optimization may be possible.

This does **not** preserve original order of array items. See:

- [How can I match the items in an array column, with a different table in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/295285/3684)

Related:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)

Comment: I might add more explanation after you clarify the exact objective.

Comment: exactly I need this, but if using distinct then I can simply add distinct in my query as well to get the return